# How to track changes made to View of Sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

Hi Everyone!

Is there a way to track the changes made to View of list in sharepoint 2007. Some random user made changes to the list view by simply using Modify this view button. Could it be tracked like the user name and date.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You might be better off posting this on sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maybe you should review you permission strategy. If a user can click a button, that means he has the right to click. If it's not desired, replan you permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can track changes made to the view from the SPChangeView class.

Find out how to use the SPChange API here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447511(v=office.14).aspx

How to create a query to look for specific changes:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447550(v=office.14).aspx

The links are for SP2010 but they will work for 2007 too.